# What would be the negatives of having both C# and VB.NET code in large ASP.NET MVC project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, vb.net

We have a development company we are working with that wants to use VB.NET since that's what they are most comfortable with and we prefer C#.  This is a pretty large ASP.NET MVC software project and all of the front end will be done in JavaScript, so the .NET is server side only.  Should we worry about them staying in VB and us in C#?  What would be negatives of proceeding like this forward?

Comment: Can you even use C# and VB.NET in the same project? I don't think you can so if that is the case you have to choose one of them.

Comment: you can do this in MVC4 actually

Comment: @kerzek Thanks for that I didn't know that was a possibility.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are the lines in the project so clear cut that you're not going to be in the VB.NET code and they're not going to be in your C#? It is rarely ever that clean and thus there will be a lot of context switching when you jump between files. You're also asking a lot of whoever is going to maintain your project. Whoever is going to maintain it should probably get the first vote for the language.

Comment: You make a very good point.  There could be some overlap but the plan is to develop parts and features independently, but I worry there could be some overlap.  Sounds like you have a strong vote that we pick one or the other.

Comment: Yes, I do. If you're going to have closed-box parts that neither side will *ever* touch, feel free to write them in whatever language you're most productive in. Otherwise, stick with one so everybody's looking at the same code throughout the project.

Comment: The problem is going to be maintenance. Whoever maintains a particular piece of code should be fluent in that language. If your people are C# people, and if you're going to be stuck maintaining the code, then you should demand the code be written by competent C# developers. If the other code will be delivered as binaries, then it doesn't matter.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Exactly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want cross language interoperability, you should consider writing your assemblies to be cls compliant (common language specification).

One of the negatives I can mention is: You must not differentiate 2 (or more) members by casing.

Why? because VB is case-insensitive and C# is case sensitive. (even though the clr is case insensitive)

Read more about [Cross Language Interoperability here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a2c7tshk.aspx)
and about [CLS compliance here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhc3fa7f.aspx)